# Export Julia output to PDF

Tags: julia

Is it possible to record output of Julia script both console output **and plotted figures**. And export it as PDF file?

I know about Jupyter but don't like it and would like to use something different. Basically I'd like to store results of script calculations in some sort of PDF report.

Comment: hmm have you considered interop with this python library : http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/mpastell/Weave.jl

Here is some extra text which appears to be required by StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, looks nice :)